# Binding data from database to a label control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, linq, ssms

I have a table in ssms with the PK id. I have an insert form on my asp.net website that allows the users to insert data into the table from the webpage. What I would like to is after the insert is complete to show a label showing the id number of what was just inserted to the user(I guess like a confirmation number). I was thinking a code like this maybe(using linq)

```
using model;
    using (ProjectEntities myEntities = new ProjectEntities()){
        var myvar = from table in myentities.table
        select table.id;
        label1.datasource = myvar;
        label1.databind;

    }
```

Comment: How are you doing the insert into the database? If your ASP.NET site is just calling a stored procedure in the database, you could set an output parameter to the value of [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql).

Comment: The insert is handle automatically using detailsview insert option

Comment: To make it easier to answer this question, you will need to provide the code that does the saving of data. That missing code is where you will be able to access the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the ADO.NET way:

```
private void GetData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING HERE");
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from TABLE1", connection);
    sqlDa.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
           TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["ColumnName1"].ToString(); //Where ColumnName is the Field from the DB that you want to display
           TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0]["ColumnName2"].ToString();
           Label1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["ColumnName3"].ToString();
           Label2.Text = dt.Rows[0]["ColumnName4"].ToString();
    }
        connection.Close();
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


   if (!Page.IsPostBack){
    GetData();
   }


}
```

Via LINQ:

```
public static Customer SelectCustomerByUser(string user)
{
    var query = (from p in dc.Customers
                 where p.No_ == user
                 select p).Single();
    return query;
}

var queryresult = CustomerClass.SelectCustomerByUser(user) as Customer;
if(queryresult!=null)
  lblStreet.Text= queryresult.Street;
```

Comment: I am using an ado.net entity model if that makes any difference.

Comment: In your ADO.NET example, the DataAdapter object (`sqlDa`) is not declared or instantiated and none of the objects that implement `IDisposable` are disposed of properly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't `DataBind` a label.  Let's assume "MyEntities" is a `DataSet`.

```
    var dat = myentities.Table[0].AsEnumerable()
//this will return more than one record.  If we assume you're looking for the "latest" in an enumeration:
    var myvar = dat.Select(t => t.ID).Last();
    label1.Text= myvar.ToString();
```